# Get post publishing date from within custom HTML block

Tags: posts, block-editor, date

I am using a custom HTML block to create a customized title cover for a post on my WordPress site. I would like to get the current post publication date (rather than hard-coding it in and having to update manually). Is there a CSS selector or JavaScript function or I can use from within a custom HTML block to get the publication date?

Comment: I can't think of a particularly elegant way to accomplish this. You could certainly use JS to grab it from somewhere else in the markup - but that won't preview correctly in the Block Editor without further work. Or you could always grab it from the REST API, but that seems fairly excessive. I think ideally you'd compose your title cover from Blocks instead of straight HTML, in which case a block or custom shortcode could provide the date for you.

Comment: WordPress core has a post date block. You could either use that or refer to its source for guidance: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-date/edit.js That block uses `useEntityProp()` to get the date.

Comment: Now that I'm not on my phone I can see I misunderstood and thought you were creating a block, not using a custom HTML block. If you can create a block I'd advise that, otherwise you'll probably just need to use an old fashioned shortcode.